# Should we allow people to ask their personal questions reagarding Islam?

Tags: discussion, personal-question

Usually people post there specific problems to stack and other people answer them.
There are some other religious sties in stack which do not allow asking personal questions. Should we follow them or not?

My opinion is that let http://islam.stackexchange.com be the best site of the world to search for queries related to Islam. But stack is community driven. So community will decide at last.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "personal questions".

Comment: personal problem like marriage, divorce etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Of course!** The mainstay of this site — as with *any* Stack Exchange site — is asking about problems you actually face.

I'm not sure where you've heard "do not allow personal questions" — perhaps the specific religious prohibitions against asking for Jewish Rabbinic advice — but I assure you that Stack Exchange has no such prohibition. Quite the opposite — Long-tailed questions about problems you, personally, *actually* face **should comprise the *majority* of questions on this site.**

If this site fills up with overly generalized, textbook-style questions, things around here will get boring really fast.

Comment: Related posts about the Jewish perspective: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/312/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146/759

Answer (score 5):

If the question is too localized (i.e. it only concerns the OP, or is worded that way) then it should be off-topic as per SE guidelines. Other than that, we should welcome these questions.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see why not, as long as their questions are researched and have not been answered and are not against the rules, than i would say it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

I would say we should allow them. It is well established in the books of hadith that people would seek the prophet's decision and advice pertaining to personal matters (and often publicly enough that they could be witnessed and eventually recorded in hadith), and he would answer them.

As long as the question is reasonably on-topic, I see no reason we should not follow the sunnah of the prophet in this regard.