# Should the question "I am unmarried, how to keep myself clean?" be closed down?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Should the question [I am unmarried, how to keep myself clean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12647/3487) be closed down because [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/3487)?

If so, then why is the community so reluctant to vote to close it down?

If not, then should it be improved?

Is this type of a pastoral advice question? Which [is](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/9049) [off](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/9049)-[topic](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1365/9049) on Christianity.SE. If so, shouldn't we adopt the same stance as is hashed succinctly out there?

Comment: I updated my answer. Moreover, link you posted seems like a question about "advice to pastors", not a question about "pastoral advice". see: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15298365#15298365

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question you have linked fall in same category as those discussed in the meta discussion. Let me quote a comment of Robert's in that discussion;

> Not to overstate the issue, but if it isn't an issue covered in by the
>   Qur'an or other canonical teachings, it isn't likely related to the
>   subject of Islam.
>   [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-a-muslim-peer-support-group#comment221_189)

We know that Qur'an and Sunnah offers many prescriptions regarding personal issues. Therefore, as I see it, questions that can be answered by quoting Qur'an and Sunnah is constructive and valuable.

The question that was discussed in the meta discussion you linked was "Muslim charities in North America" which was more about the Muslims than subject of Islam.

> Try not to turn this into a issues or political forum, or a place to
>   ask "What do Muslims think about [X]?" We are not not here to discuss
>   Islamic countries or their conflicts nor are we here to solve the
>   world's problems from an Islamic prospective.
>
> This is a site about the subject of Islam — and creating a great
>   canonical Q&A resource for those who come after.

Moreover, we have already established that it is encouraged to ask such questions, see [Should we allow people to ask their personal questions reagarding Islam?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/should-we-allow-people-to-ask-their-personal-questions-reagarding-islam)

---

### Answer Update:

Islam is very different than Christianity in that regard, because we have many hadith tailored for specific situations. Islam, as a religion, is something that govern most aspects of Muslims' day to day lives. As long as the question is well-defined and can be answered by referencing Qur'an, Sunnah or notable scholars, I think such questions will be fine. They might get closed for other reasons though, such as being "too broad".

I think, *what does islam say/instruct*, part is always implied, because this is a Q/A site about Islam.

Comment: Question update. I think it's more of a pastoral advice question. Which could be dangerous to answer. Better safe then sorry. The question should be concretely pointed on the subject of Islam what does Islam say/instruct, not what should I do (that's subjective and (could be) dangerous).